# WSO2 IS error 389DS, cannot find admin

Tags: ldap, wso2, wso2-identity-server

I have connected OpenLdap with Identity Server(IS) and authentication was also successful. Now I am trying to connect an 389 Directory Server with IS. Connection is successful but I'm getting an error,

```
Caused by: org.wso2.carbon.user.core.UserStoreException: Admin user can not be created in primary user store. User store is read only. Please pick a user name which is exist in the primary u
ser store as Admin user
```

My configuration is,

```
<Configuration>
    <AddAdmin>False</AddAdmin>
        <AdminRole>wsoadmin</AdminRole>
        <AdminUser>
            <UserName>banderson</UserName>
            <Password>*****</Password>
        </AdminUser>
        <EveryOneRoleName>everyone</EveryOneRoleName> <!-- By default users in this role sees the registry root -->
        <Property name="isCascadeDeleteEnabled">true</Property>
        <Property name="dataSource">jdbc/WSO2CarbonDB</Property>
    </Configuration>

<UserStoreManager class="org.wso2.carbon.user.core.ldap.ReadOnlyLDAPUserStoreManager">
        <Property name="TenantManager">org.wso2.carbon.user.core.tenant.CommonHybridLDAPTenantManager</Property>
        <Property name="ConnectionURL">ldap://URL:389/o=NetscapeRoot</Property>
        <Property name="ConnectionName">cn=Directory Manager</Property>
        <Property name="ConnectionPassword">password</Property>
        <Property name="UserSearchBase">ou=People,dc=example,dc=edu</Property>
        <Property name="UserNameAttribute">uid</Property> <!--i even tried "cn" here -->
        <Property name="UserNameSearchFilter">(&amp;(objectClass=person)(uid=?))</Property>
        <Property name="UserNameListFilter">(objectClass=person)</Property>
        <Property name="DisplayNameAttribute"/>
        <Property name="ReadGroups">true</Property>
        <Property name="GroupSearchBase">ou=system</Property>
        <Property name="GroupNameAttribute">cn</Property>
        <Property name="GroupNameSearchFilter">(&amp;(objectClass=groupOfNames)(cn=?))</Property>
        <Property name="GroupNameListFilter">(objectClass=groupOfNames)</Property>
        <Property name="MembershipAttribute">member</Property>
        <Property name="BackLinksEnabled">false</Property>
        <Property name="UsernameJavaRegEx">[a-zA-Z0-9._-|//]{3,30}$</Property>
        <Property name="PasswordJavaRegEx">^[\S]{5,30}$</Property>
        <Property name="RolenameJavaRegEx">[a-zA-Z0-9._-|//]{3,30}$</Property>
        <Property name="SCIMEnabled">false</Property>
        <Property name="PasswordHashMethod">PLAIN_TEXT</Property>
        <Property name="MultiAttributeSeparator">,</Property>
        <Property name="MaxUserNameListLength">100</Property>
        <Property name="MaxRoleNameListLength">100</Property>
        <Property name="UserRolesCacheEnabled">true</Property>
        <Property name="ConnectionPoolingEnabled">true</Property>
        <Property name="LDAPConnectionTimeout">5000</Property>
        <Property name="ReadTimeout"/>
        <Property name="RetryAttempts"/>
        <Property name="ReplaceEscapeCharactersAtUserLogin">true</Property>
    </UserStoreManager>
```

This is my user.ldif,

```
dn: cn=admin,dc=example,dc=edu
objectClass: simpleSecurityObject
objectClass: organizationalRole
cn: admin
userPassword: password
description: LDAP administrator
dn: uid=jsmith,ou=People,dc=example,dc=edu
objectClass: organizationalPerson
objectClass: person
objectClass: top
objectClass: inetOrgPerson
givenName: Joe
uid: jsmith
sn: Smith
cn: John Smith
userPassword: password
dn: uid=banderson,ou=People,dc=example,dc=edu
objectClass: organizationalPerson
objectClass: person
objectClass: top
objectClass: inetOrgPerson
givenName: Bob
uid: banderson
sn: Anderson
cn: Bob Anderson
userPassword: password
```

ds-setup info,

```
[General]
AdminDomain = example.edu
ConfigDirectoryAdminID = admin
ConfigDirectoryAdminPwd = admin
ConfigDirectoryLdapURL = ldap://localhost:389/o=NetscapeRoot
FullMachineName = localhost
ServerRoot = /usr/lib64/dirsrv
SuiteSpotGroup = nobody
SuiteSpotUserID = nobody
[admin]
Port = 9830
ServerAdminID = admin
ServerAdminPwd = admin
ServerIpAddress = 0.0.0.0
SysUser = nobody
[slapd]
AddOrgEntries = Yes
AddSampleEntries = No
InstallLdifFile = suggest
RootDN = cn=Directory Manager
RootDNPwd = password
ServerIdentifier = dir
ServerPort = 389
SlapdConfigForMC = yes
Suffix = dc=example,dc=edu
UseExistingMC = No
```

Ldap Structure,
http://prntscr.com/ay7p6r

Kindly help me debug this, I have gone through the WSO2 docs tried several combinations but could not solve this.

Thanks

---edit---
Secondary user store config file,

```
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><UserStoreManager class="org.wso2.carbon.user.core.ldap.ReadOnlyLDAPUserStoreManager">
      <Property name="ConnectionURL">ldap://URL:389</Property>
      <Property name="ConnectionName">cn=Directory Manager</Property>
      <Property encrypted="true" name="ConnectionPassword">U57XaWZIJHoj8hyMpGTHriXtOdSwZwEBSPjvHmDM/Td9QPGFo1obCWbW/z6W5ebVAKdsIQ7Tii9sUYtNptW2DH14SfUbPTZO80dIl3W2LPMLlWQVJ8DyDedAJo9WgP8490r56TjoJKHN4J5EdJwApYuQPDZMsuBSj80gaAJlpfk=</Property>
      <Property name="UserSearchBase">ou=People,dc=example,dc=edu</Property>
      <Property name="UserNameAttribute">uid</Property>
      <Property name="UserNameSearchFilter">(&amp;(objectClass=person)(uid=?))</Property>
      <Property name="UserNameListFilter">(objectClass=person)</Property>
      <Property name="UserDNPattern"/>
      <Property name="DisplayNameAttribute">uid</Property>
      <Property name="Disabled">false</Property>
      <Property name="ReadGroups">true</Property>
      <Property name="GroupSearchBase">ou=Groups,dc=wso2,dc=org</Property>
      <Property name="GroupNameAttribute">cn</Property>
      <Property name="GroupNameSearchFilter">(&amp;(objectClass=groupOfNames)(cn=?))</Property>
      <Property name="GroupNameListFilter">(objectClass=groupOfNames)</Property>
      <Property name="RoleDNPattern"/>
      <Property name="MembershipAttribute">member</Property>
      <Property name="MemberOfAttribute"/>
      <Property name="BackLinksEnabled">false</Property>
      <Property name="ReplaceEscapeCharactersAtUserLogin">true</Property>
      <Property name="SCIMEnabled">false</Property>
      <Property name="PasswordHashMethod">PLAIN_TEXT</Property>
      <Property name="MultiAttributeSeparator">,</Property>
      <Property name="MaxUserNameListLength">100</Property>
      <Property name="MaxRoleNameListLength">100</Property>
      <Property name="UserRolesCacheEnabled">true</Property>
      <Property name="ConnectionPoolingEnabled">false</Property>
      <Property name="LDAPConnectionTimeout">5000</Property>
      <Property name="ReadTimeout">5000</Property>
      <Property name="RetryAttempts">0</Property>
      <Property name="DomainName">389ds.com</Property>
      <Property name="Description">testing 389 DS</Property>
</UserStoreManager>
```

Comment: Can you check <AddAdmin>false</AddAdmin> instead of 'False'?

Comment: Yes, tried that, facing same error. Similar configuration worked with OpenLdap. But having issues with 389 DS

Comment: I'm not sure the issue here. What you can do is, first try this as a secondary user store from the management console in a fresh IS pack and identify what are the correct configurations. Then a conf file for that userstore will be created at repository/deployment/server/userstore/ . Then we can add the as the primary user store by referring the that.

Comment: I have added it as a secondary user store and yes I can login through the users of my 389 DS. Now what should I do to make it primary user store

Comment: Now check the configuration in file that I have mentioned and check if there are any differences with user-mgt.xml you used when adding it as primary data store.

Comment: Well there are a lot of differences, I dont know what changes should I do to make it work as primary data store, I have edited my question and added the latest config file have a look.

Comment: can u send a gist of it?

Comment: Shall we replace the properties of your previous configuration with these set of properties and try?

Comment: Yes I have tried that, i still get the same error.

Comment: Can you enable the debug logs for user.core and share the logs?

Comment: Kindly find the logs here, pastebin.com/L93QVzrK

Comment: I don't see the error message you have mentioned in the question in your debug log, it has error saying "Admin role can not be created in primary user store.". Are getting this new log when you add the properties of secondary user store?
Also in the setup with this ldap added as secondary user store, is it possible to list the groups in that user store? Is that group list contain the 'wsoadmin' role?

Answer (score 2):

As per the logs you shared in the comment, you are getting following error,

`Caused by: org.wso2.carbon.user.core.UserStoreException: Admin role can not be created in primary user store. Add-Admin has been set to false. Please pick a Role name which is exist in the primary user store as Admin Role`

This happens because as per configs you specified in the user-mgt.xml, admin role "wsoadmin" cannot be found in the 389 Directory server.

And it seems like your group related configurations also wrong in the user-mgt.xml. If you don't want to pick group information from 389 directory server following property in the user-mgt.xml,
`<Property name="ReadGroups">true</Property>`

Above property will void checking on group information on the directory server and automatically switch to looking groups from IS internal database, create a internal role called "wsoadmin", assign admin user "banderson" to role internal wsoadmin role and complete the startup process successfully.

HTH,
DarRay

Answer (score 0):

In your user store manager configuration, you have 
**org.wso2.carbon.user.core.ldap.ReadOnlyLDAPUserStoreManager**

But, can you try the same after adding the configuration under the class
**org.wso2.carbon.user.core.ldap.ReadWriteLDAPUserStoreManager**

Also set **true** so that if the admin user does not exist, it will add.